# How to rename Abstract title in Memoir?

Tags: memoir, abstract, naming

I'm trying to customize the **Abstract** of a memoir document using the following command:

```
 \renewcommand{\abstractname}{Executive Summary}
```

The problem is that it actually has no effect. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you construct a minimal example that shows the problem? Out of the box, this should do what you want.

Comment: Put the command before the abstract.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your command is correct. However, I guess you're using the `babel` langage package which overrides it. In that case, use the `\addto` command of `babel`, i.e. replace

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Executive Summary}
```

by

```
\addto{\captionsenglish}{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Executive Summary}}
```

That applies to further names as well, such as `\prefacename`, `\refname` etc. You can use one `\addto` command for all. If you use a different language, replace `\captionsenglish` by the similar command corresponding to the language.

Comment: Thanks.. your guess is right, and it works :) LyX adds the **babel** package by default although I don't think I need it. I still don't know why it overrides the abstract name, but I'll use your solution.

Comment: @Tom Perhaps with further information, such as your (reduced) source code. Perhaps post a new question if it's long or if your situation is different.

Comment: Why do I get `! Undefined control sequence. \addto`?

Comment: @AndréFratelli I assume because you did not load babel. But then a direct `\renewcommand` should work. Otherwise you could just ask a new question with all details you have.

Comment: I ended up here because `\renewcommand` wasn't working. This solution didn't either. I'm putting a pin on this issue for now, but I just might follow your recommendation later. Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233882/change-abstract-title-name-in-els-article-class) did it for me, if anybody else comes looking for a solution.

Comment: can we apply same approach for the references name?

Comment: @alper Yes, it should be with `\refname`.

Answer (score 3):

And, of course,

```
\addto{\captionsitalian}{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Contenuto}}
```

if the language is Italian, and, generally:

```
\addto{\captionsLANGUAGE}{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Contenuto}}
```

Comment: For what it's worth `captionsenglish` is not the same as `captionsbritish` !?