# ! LaTeX Error: Environment execsummary undefined

Tags: errors

I just need help with this problem that I couldn't find the right answer for about a month now. execsummary is my file name and this it the code in this file:

```
\begin{execsummary}

Write your executive summary here. 

\end{execsummary}
```

Everytime I compile the file I always get this error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
("D:/CP/execsummary.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, and so on... loaded.

! LaTeX Error: Environment execsummary undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \begin{execsummary}

?
```

I just installed the latest version of MikTex and I always get this error. Please help.

Comment: TeX doesn't automatically know every environment, you have to install the package which provides that environment, and then you need to add `\usepackage{<package name that provides env execsummary>}` before `\begin{document}`. And welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: What documentclass are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you make a confusion between the filename and the document structure.
Basically, the general structure of the LaTeX file must be :

```
\documentclass[<options>]{<class>}
<some packages>
<some definitions>
\begin{document}
   <text and commands>
\end{documment>
```

in `<text and commands>` you can use any environment defined in  the preambule 
(ie in `LaTeX`, `<class>`, or `<some packages>` or `<some definitions>`).

Without knowledge of the class and packages you use,one can't possible to provide an accurate answer. If you simply want to have an abstract renamed 'Executive Summary', you can put in `<some definitions>` the line:
  `\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Executive Summary}`
or for further customization something like
  `\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\slshape Executive Summary}`
but the abstract will still be defined with `\begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}`.

As you apparently use `babel` package, you must have a look to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24754/how-to-rename-abstract-title-in-memoir) on `tex.stackexchange.com`

If this does not solve the problem provide a minimal working example !