# Change "Abstract" Title Name in els Article Class

Tags: naming, abstract, elsarticle

Good day, I've searched the archives and have tried using

```
\renewcommand\abstractname{summary}
```

to change the name of the abstract, but was not successful.

Here's the working example of my code:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\renewcommand\abstractname{summary}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}

\journal{Journal Name}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Characterization of a Murine Embryonic Stem Cell Line}
\author{Daniel D.}
\address{State University}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}

\section*{Introduction}

\section*{Results}

\section*{Discussion}

\section*{Experimental Procedures}
```

Thank you for any help or insight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Current versions of [`elsarticle`](//ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle) allows you to set the abstract title using `\abstracttitle{<title>}`. The default is set using `\abstracttitle{Abstract}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\journal{Journal Name}
\abstracttitle{Summary}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{My title}
\author{My title}
\address{My Address}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe changing `Abstract` into `\abstractname` and then doing `\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Summary}` is even better.

Comment: I've tried the above MWE on Overleaf, and the abstract is still titled **Abstract**. Has anyone else encountered this issue and been able to resolve it?

Comment: @NauticalMile: Use `\abstracttitle{Summary}`. I've updated my answers, since this is now part of the [`elsarticle`](//ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle).