# How to put an arabic title in the abstract

Tags: arabic, abstract, arabtex

i'm using the package arabtex to write in arabic , but for the abstract the output is not printed correctly
the command that i've used is

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\RL{ملخص}}
```

and also tried

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\begin{arabtext}ملخص \end{arabtext}}
```

the complete .tex file is

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\RL{ملخص}}
\begin{abstract}  
\setstretch{1.3}
\setcode{utf8}
\RL{
 في هذا التقرير، وردت إشارة إلى تنفيذ نظام كشف الوجه. والهدف من ذلك هو الكشف عن وجوه الناس المهتمين في منشور
  معين.
لقد إستعملنا لهذا الغرض لوحة الكترونية \LR{Raspberry pi 2} بالإضافة إلى وحدة الكاميرا الخاصة بها لملاحقة الوجوه و العين.
يستخدم  تطبيق كشف الوجه  خوارزمية قوية  لفيولا جونز مع  تدريب المصنف للكشف عن الوجه الإنساني والعينين، عن طريق اختيار أفضل مصنف ممكن.
سيتم حفظ البيانات لكل إعلان في قاعدة بيانات \LR{MySQL} . وقد تم إنشاء تطبيق ويب لهذا الغرض والذي سيمكن المستخدم من   
معرفة عدد الأشخاص  والمدة الإجمالية للمشاهدة في الفترة (ساعة، يوم، شهر )  على شكل رسم بياني.
}
\end{abstract}
```

but the work appear in the paragraph not as a title

[image: The title is printed inside the paragraph]

for the rest :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{report}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}   
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[french]{varioref}


\usepackage{arabtex} 
\usepackage{utf8}

 \usepackage{pifont}  % for some special characters 

\begin{document}
  \include{title}
  \include{ArabeAbstract}  

 \end{document}
```

Any hints ?

Comment: I don't understand Arabic nor can I read the letters, but perhaps `\protect\RL{}` in the `\abstractname` redefinition might work.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks but  it doesn't work !

Comment: Please complete your minimal working example, so that it can be compiled and we know which document class you’re using, etc.

Comment: @Thérèse sorry ... i have added the preambule you can compile it now i guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\addto{\captionsfrench}{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Executive Summary}}` see this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24754/how-to-rename-abstract-title-in-memoir). (Note: I've replaced `\captionsenglish` with `\captionsfrench` since the last option is the active option, see this [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Arabic_script)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{report}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}   
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[french]{varioref}


\usepackage{arabtex} 
\usepackage{utf8}

\usepackage{pifont}  % for some special characters 

\setstretch{1.3}
\setcode{utf8}



\addto{\captionsfrench}{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\RL{ملخص}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}  

\RL{
 في هذا التقر وردت إشارة إلى تنفيذ نظام كشف الوجه. والهدف من ذلك هو الكشف عن وجوه الناس المهتمين في منشور
  معين.
لقد إستعملنا لهذا الغرض لوحة الكترونية \LR{Raspberry pi 2} بالإضافة إلى وحدة الكاميرا الخاصة بها لملاحقة الوجوه و العين.
يستخدم  تطبيق كشف الوجه  خوارزمية قوية  لفيولا جونز مع  تدريب المصنف للكشف عن الوجه الإنساني والعينين عن طريق اختيار أفضل مصنف ممكن.
سيتم حفظ البيانات لكل إعلان في قاعدة بيانات \LR{MySQL} . وقد تم إنشاء تطبيق ويب لهذا الغرض والذي سيمكن المستخدم من   
معرفة عدد الأشخاص  والمدة الإجمالية للمشاهدة في الفترة (ساعة يوم شهر )  على شكل رسم بياني.
}
\end{abstract}



 \end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The solution posted by @CroCo worked perfectly , thanks to him . Another solution that i have found is to simply move `\setcode{utf8}` before `\begin{abstract}` , that worked , and here is what the file should look like:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{report}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}   
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[french]{varioref}

\usepackage{arabtex} 
\usepackage{utf8}

\usepackage{pifont}  % for some special characters 


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\RL{ملخص}}
\setcode{utf8}
\begin{abstract}  %% ملخص
\setstretch{1.3}
\RL{
 في هذا التقرير، وردت إشارة إلى تنفيذ نظام كشف الوجه. والهدف من ذلك هو الكشف عن وجوه الناس المهتمين في منشور
  معين.
لقد إستعملنا لهذا الغرض لوحة الكترونية \LR{Raspberry pi 2} بالإضافة إلى وحدة الكاميرا الخاصة بها لملاحقة الوجوه و العين.
يستخدم  تطبيق كشف الوجه  خوارزمية قوية  لفيولا جونز مع  تدريب المصنف للكشف عن الوجه الإنساني والعينين، عن طريق اختيار أفضل مصنف ممكن.
سيتم حفظ البيانات لكل إعلان في قاعدة بيانات \LR{MySQL} . وقد تم إنشاء تطبيق ويب لهذا الغرض والذي سيمكن المستخدم من   
معرفة عدد الأشخاص  والمدة الإجمالية للمشاهدة في الفترة (ساعة، يوم، شهر )  على شكل رسم بياني.
}
\end{abstract}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Please always remember to add the complete code so that people can double check your answer.

Comment: @CroCo ok done .